# Django Rest Framework - Nested relationships as Flat

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#nested-relationships

It is not clear from the documentation if and how it's possible to use the same principle of nested relationships to render a flat JSON.

For example:

```
"nest": {
    "b": {
        "c": {
            "d": {
                "e": {
                    "E": "echo"
                },
                "D": "delta"
            },
            "C": "charlie"
        },
        "B": "beta"
    },
    "A": "alpha"
}

"flat": {
    "A": "alpha",
    "B": "beta",
    "C": "charlie",
    "D": "delta",
    "E": "echo"
}
```

How can the `flat` JSON be achieved?

Comment: You can write your own custom serializer.

Comment: I've read the tutorial and the API page on serializers, I still don't know how to do that, can you please point me in the right direction with a small example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets assume your code looks like

```
mymodel_queryset = MyModel.objects.all()
```

So what you can do is write your own custom serializer as follows:

```
def my_custom_serializer(queryset):
   res = []
   for q in queryset:
      ob = {'name': q.name, 'city': q.city.name} # Notice how i use the relation here for city. So the nested relation is becoming flat for city
      res.append(ob)
   return res
```

Now in your code you can use

```
 data = my_custom_serializer(mymodel_queryset)
 return Response(status=status.HTTP_200_OK, data=data)
```

Hope this helps you. :)

Comment: Of course, please give me some time to look at this and as soon as I figure it out I will accept the answer. This way I won't be in the situation where I'm still stuck and need to make a new question :)